# Is this all there is to scope?

Tags: javascript

Trying to get scope down. This is what I have so far. Anything to add?

Identifier keywords: `var` `let` `const` and ‘implicit variable’ e.g. `x = 1`.

Block: `{}`

**Function scope:** no matter the identifier keyword, any variable declared within the parameters or block of a function cannot be accessed outside.

**Block scope:** for any block that isn’t a function’s block, `let` and `const`prevent identifier being accessed out-with function. This includes the parameters for things like for loops i.e.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
  return 5;
}
console.log(i) //results in ReferenceError.
```

Both function and block scope have access to anything directly ‘upwards’ of it e.g. `f()`can return `w` but not `x`.

```js
v = 1;
f = function () {
    w = 1;
    f2 = function () {
        console.log(w);
        console.log(x);
    }
    f2();
}

f3 = function () {
    x = 1;
}

f();
```

When a function or block scope is referencing a variable that is same-named, the variable closest to the scope (all the way down to the scope’s own variable) has preference.

Also, you cannot have a same-named variable, in the same scope, when either both are `const` or `let`.

Comment: Pretty much, except that you should use `var`, `let` or `const` in that second snippet there…

Comment: Close voters - When I read the title I expected to be voting to close as too broad as well. :-) But when I read the question I thought "Actually, that's specific enough I can answer it." Obviously opinions can vary.

Comment: I agree with @T.J.Crowder this is definitely answerable. At first glance I thought there would be nothing *to* answer because the question seemed to cover most upon closer inspection, there were some relatively minor gaps to fill which T.J.'s answer does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of the basics there, yes. Some notes/additions:

> Identifier keywords: var let const and ‘implicit variable’ e.g. x = 1.

- `class` and `function` declarations also create identifier bindings in the scope where they appear (for the class name / function name)
- Named `class` and `function` expressions don't create an identifier binding in the scope where they appear, but they do create one for the scope *within* the class or function (for the class name / function name)
- "implicit variable" => "implicit **global**". Use strict mode so that assigning to an undeclared identifier is the error it always should have been. (More in this old post on my old blog: [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html))

> **Function scope:** no matter the identifier keyword, any variable declared within the parameters or block of a function cannot be accessed outside.

Right.

> **Block scope:** for any block that isn’t a function’s block, `let` and `const`prevent identifier being accessed out-with function. This includes the parameters for things like for loops i.e.
>
> ```js
> for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
>   return 5;
> }
> console.log(i) //results in ReferenceError.
> ```

They prevent access outside the *block* (not the function; I think that was just a typo in your question). The variables don't exist outside the block, so you can't access them outside the block.

`class` declarations work the same way `let` and `const` do. That is, `let`, `const`, and `class` have *block* scope. `var` has *function* scope. For `function` declarations...it's complicated; declaring functions in non-function blocks is best avoided. Use a function expression instead.

> Both function and block scope have access to anything directly ‘upwards’ of it

Not just *directly*, anything in **any** enclosing scope:

```js
const globalScope = 1;

function foo() {
    const functionScope = 2;
    
    {
        const blockScope = 3;
        
        console.log(globalScope);
        console.log(functionScope);
        console.log(blockScope);
    }
}

foo();
```

We can even throw module scope in there:

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script>
// Old-style script, so this is a global
const globalScope = 1;
</script>
<script type="module">
// Module script, so this is a module-level variable,
// not a global
const moduleScope = 2;

function foo() {
    const functionScope = 3;
    
    {
        const blockScope = 4;
        
        console.log(globalScope);
        console.log(moduleScope);
        console.log(functionScope);
        console.log(blockScope);
    }
}

foo();

// If we add another old-style script, it only has access to the global
// Note: Don't add scripts this way, this is a cheap-and-dirty trick just
// for the purposes of the example
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = `
    // Here at global scope, we only have one of those
    console.log(typeof globalScope);    // number
    console.log(typeof moduleScope);    // undefined
    console.log(typeof functionScope);  // undefined
    console.log(typeof blockScope);     // undefined
`;
document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Fun fact: This access to enclosing scopes is why global variables work; global variables are the outermost layer (actually two layers) of scope.

> When a function or block scope is referencing a variable that is same-named, the variable closest to the scope (all the way down to the scope’s own variable) has preference.

Right. Resolution is innermost-to-outermost.

> Also, you cannot have a same-named variable, in the same scope, when either both are `const` or `let`.

More specifically, you can't have more than one variable with the same name in a scope. You can *write* `var x` more than once, but only one `x` is created. You can have multiple `function` declarations in a scope, but the last one wins (ignoring block stuff; again, `function` declarations in blocks are complicated). `let`, `const`, and `class` make doing that an error, as it's usually not intentional.

---

There are a couple of other scopes worth noting:

- **Outer global scope**: The outer global scope is the scope that uses the global object as its binding object. This is why on browsers, properties of `window` are globals. This is where `var` identifier bindings are created (they're properties of `window` that can't be deleted), as well as global-level `function` declarations.
- **Inner global scope**: The inner global scope is where the identifier bindings created by `let`, `const`, and `class` declarations at global scope go. They aren't properties of the global object.
- **Module scope**: Modules have their own scope, nested just within global scope.
- **`for` scope**: A `for` loop has its own scope whether the body of the `for` is a block or a single non-block statement. Or I should say *scopes*, plural, because each iteration of the loop gets its own scope, which is why using `let` or `const` in a `for` loop creates *separate* variables for each iteration, solving the closures-in-loops problem.
- **Parameter list scope**: Non-simple parameter lists (one that use ES2015+ features like destructuring, default values, rest) have their own scope nested between the containing scope and the function's scope.
- **`with` scope**: `with` is deprecated, and disallowed in strict mode, but the body of the `with` has its own scope (even if it's not a block).

Comment: *(FWIW, I cover the above in my new book,* JavaScript: The New Toys, *which covers the additions to JavaScript in ES2015-ES2020 and along the way explains scope and bindings. See my profile for details if you're interested.)*